# Custom align, three \beta = statements, so the beta is custom aligned vertically, and the matrices/vectors are all vertically aligned

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices, arrays

Something like:

\beta = [], \quad \beta = [], \quad \beta = [].

So that the three forms of beta fit on one line.

I want the \beta = to valign with the first element of the vector/matrix.

I want all the remaining betas to be in the same position.

I want the [] matrix/vectors to be all vertically aligned.

I want it to work within `\begin{equation}` environment, `\begin{align}` environment, `\begin{array}` environment, `$math$`, and/or `\[ \]`

Please see attached image, and thanks in advance!

monte

{x:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**
Verifying that solution provided by David Carlisle works with font size changes

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{delarray}

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{24}{14}{14}

\begin{document}
\[
\beta =
\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{c}\rbrack v_1\\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ v_4 \end{array}
, \quad \beta =
\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{c}\rbrack v_1\\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ v_4 \\ v_5 \\ v_6 \end{array}
, \quad \beta =
\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{c}\rbrack v_1\\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ v_4 \\ v_5 \\ v_6 \\ v_7 \\ v_8 \\ v_9 \end{array}
.
\]
\end{document}
```

---

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{delarray}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{c}\rbrack 1\\2\\3\end{array}
+
\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{c}\rbrack 1\\2\\3\\4\\5\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: really, there should be a general question about how to use `[t]`, `[b]`, and `[c]` to align various objects.

Comment: @barbarabeeton although here it is specific delarray package syntax, if you use `\left[\begin{array}[t]` you get something rather different.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work with the regular array environment, so I will probably have a collision in the final document (which uses the default array package)

Comment: @mshaffer No. delarray and (half of) array were written by the same person, and delarray uses array. They are as compatible as two packages can ever be.

Comment: @david-carlisle Yes, generally you are correct, but the manuscript template prepared by a journal does have some sort of collision and only the betas = ., appear the [] and everything inside are gone.  I will compile independently and include

Comment: @mshaffer that happens even after including delarray? weird.

Comment: @david-carlisle Yes, I place it and a few custom Beta styles right before begin document.  I have experienced "weirdness" related to array in this style package ... informs, I believe it is informs1.cls ... both the custom Beta styles and the delarray work in an independent document

Comment: The log file says delarray was GTG:  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\delarray.sty"
Package: delarray 2014/10/28 v1.01 array delimiter package (DPC)
)

Comment: @mshaffer found a copy of the class online `%%%%%%%%%% dcolumn.sty - first original then modified
%% File: dcolumn.dtx Copyright (C) 1992-1996 David Carlisle`  hmmm they mess with array internals:-)

Comment: @david-carlisle I am glad I am not crazy, I say that line as well.

Comment: @david-carlisle I found the collision, it wasn't the informs.cls file, it was \usepackage{mathptmx} for Times Roman Font.  I guess I need to build .afms so I can get directly to Times New Roman, and see if that "unbreaks" the situation.

Comment: @david-carlisle  Any thoughts on why \usepackage{mathptmx} breaks this delarray approach?

Comment: @mshaffer I can't see any way mathptmx can affect this, and adding `\usepackage{mathptmx}` to the above gives different fonts but the same layout.